# How to remove three dots at the end of post thumbnail on blogger

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, blogs, blogger

How to remove three dots (...) at the end of post thumbnail (See image, using Below URL) on blogger? I don’t have sound Knowledge in JavaScript or jQuery. I have given my post thumbnail JavaScript below. Please Check the JavaScript code and Let me know how to change it.

Example Image URL: http://bit.ly/1OU4f9a

JavaScript URL: http://bit.ly/1OjbqEX

Comment: `textElement.substring(0, textElement.length-3)`? Sorry not familiar with blogger. also no idea what the JavaScript in that JavaScript URL is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, replace `return d+"\x2E\x2E\x2E"` with `return d`.

Comment: Dear Sir, Your answer in working better. thank for it. Now i am facing new problem. this is my new question [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34715544/how-to-stop-post-images-loading-in-blogger-main-page