# How to stop post images loading in blogger main page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, blogger

Images that inside post pages is loading on blogger main page. I want to that post images loading only post page. If you have answer for this problem. Please let me know. Thank you.
This is my blogger URL: http://sritestweb.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the post page images from the main page. And load it using javascript on load event of the main page.

```
//This function should be called on main page load event.
function onPageLoad(){
  //imgcontainer is 'id' of containing element.
  var container = document.getElementsById("imgcontainer");
   var img = document.createElement('img');
            img.setAttribute('src', imagePath);
    container.appendChild(img);
}
```

Doing this way, the rendering of the main page will not wait for the post images to get loaded.

Comment: Dear Sir, I tried Your Method but it doesn't Working.

Comment: please check this blog on how to defer loading images [link] https://varvy.com/pagespeed/defer-images.html.   And also I checked your blog the *.woff file is taking around 726ms to load. Load the fonts only that if you are reallyy using in your page.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me. Please check.
'default.jpg' is the one which you want to show before the actual image load. Keep the size of 'default.jpg'to minimum.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
<script>
    function init() {
        var imgDefer = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
        for (var i=0; i<imgDefer.length; i++) {
        if(imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src')) {
        imgDefer[i].setAttribute('src',imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src'));
    } } }

</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
<img data-src="original-image1.jpg"  src="default.jpg">
</img>

<img data-src="original-image2.jpg" src="default.jpg">
</img>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dear Sir, your method is working while have only one image in post and it can not apply directly in blogger post. above code isn't suitable for blogger post. i want to optimized code for Blogger.  thank you.

Comment: I tested the code it applied for all the images in my page. By the way I made a small typo mistake in the above code. The second image 'data-src' is wrongly typed as 'date-src'.

Comment: Your method is working but it can not apply directly in blogger post. if you find simple method for this process. please let me know it. thank for your help.

Comment: Dear Sir, In my website defer (data-src) images loading after other website stuff. i want to put defer images loading first. how can do it? see my blog [link] http://vishwatestblog.blogspot.com/